# Is there any way to configure the initial AppDomain?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I want to make it so my primary AppDomain has [`ShadowCopyAssemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) set to true.

Is there something I can do (for example perhaps a manifest setting I am missing) that will let the first AppDomain loaded in my executable have have that property set to true or is my only option to create a 2nd AppDomain and have my program do the bulk of it's work in that 2nd domain?

The target environment is a self hosted service, but knowing how to do it for Console or windows applications would be good to know too.

Comment: Have you tried `AppDomainSetup.ShadowCopyFiles`? Does it work for you?

Comment: @Abhi That is for creating new domains, once the domain is created you can not modify it. However I think I found the solution, I will be posting an answer shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After posting the question I discovered it is a setting you can pass in to the `App.config` file. What you need to do is set the configuration settings [`<appDomainManagerType>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630885%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`<appDomainManagerAssembly>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630886%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and point it at a 2nd assembly that contains a AppDomainManager.

Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
    <runtime>
      <appDomainManagerType value="DomainManager.ShadowDomainManager" />
      <appDomainManagerAssembly
         value="DomainManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Manager:

```
using System;

namespace DomainManager
{
    public class ShadowDomainManager : AppDomainManager
    {
        public override void InitializeNewDomain(AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo)
        {
            base.InitializeNewDomain(appDomainInfo); //Currently does not do anything.
            appDomainInfo.ShadowCopyFiles = "true";
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this will cause the initial domain to load with `ShadowCopyFiles` set to true.

Comment: I deleted my answer since this is more comprehensive. You probably should call `base.InitializeNewDomain` even if it doesn't do anything right now.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work. I'm still unable to delete my entry assembly. I've tried resetting my .NET version back to 4.0.